# Listen locations in background service

Tags: android, service, background, gps, location

I am doing an application that listen locations eventually on background service to send to server and process it.

So, I was trying to do 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22816875/retrieve-location-from-service) but it didn't work fine for me.

Which is the best way to do this?

Which is the difference between old LocationManager and new LocationManager? (integrated in Google Play Services)

Comment: what difficulty you are facing /

Comment: Only that. Listen locations each 30 minutes (for example) and send to server. The main difficulty is, getting locations from a Serivce.

Comment: u need to search about fusedLocation listner it will work..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8352516 and http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_location_based_services.htm